# how can two array marge each inside object key are matching it Cross?

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I have two array user and game

```
$user =[
       {
           "name": "jone",
           "id": "100"
       },
       {
           "name": "Peters",
           "id": "200"
       }
   ]

$game = [
       {
           "name": "tennis",
           "level": "05",
           "user_id": "100"
       },
       {
           "name": "football",
           "level": "03",
           "user_id": "100"
       },
       {
           "name": "football",
           "level": "05",
           "user_id": "200"
       }
   ]
```

I want to get a result like this using PHP / Laravel

```
$user = [
          {
              "name": "jone",
              "id": "100"
              "game": [
                  {
                      "name": "tennis",
                      "level": "05",
                      "user_id": "100"
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "football",
                      "level": "03",
                      "user_id": "100"
                  }
              ],
          },
          {
              "name": "Peters",
              "id": "200"
              "game": [
                  {
                      "name": "football",
                      "level": "05",
                      "user_id": "200"
                  }
              ],
          }
      ],
```

any one help me

Comment: This is not a code writing service, you are supposed to at least show us some attempt you made yourself to try and solve this.

Comment: I am new in PHP help me

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, it will explain you that you are supposed to try before, do some research, give a reproducible example of what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that I should not provide an answer to this "non-question". I still do so, as I think it might carry some learning value.

The idea is, **not** to cycle each game for each user (as the naive approach would be), as this simply doesn't scale. It is much better to use a matching array and then sort the games into it:

```
//Prepare matching array
$user_games=array();
foreach ($user as $u) {
        $u['game']=array();
        $user_games[$u['id']]=$u;
}

//Sort games into matching array
foreach ($game as $g) {
        $user_games[$g['user_id']]['game'][]=$g;
}
```

This way a new game will not create n cycles (n being the number of users), but only one.

```
print_r($user_games);
```

creates the desired output. If the user IDs as indices are a problem, just use

```
print_r(array_values($user_games);
```